# How do I Window until a criteria is met within my Window?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a set of data with 3 columns of interest. The first column is a date representing the month. The second is a column with some starting amount for that month. The third is a column that represents a reduction in amount for that month. I have a number of rows of data for each month over a period of time.

For example, we might get a date of 2020-01-01, with a starting amount of 5MM and a reduction of 2MM. This would mean we expect to have a remaining amount of 3MM at the end of the month.

I need to calculate how long it will take to burndown this starting amount over the next months.

Given the above example, if we start with 5MM, and that month consumes 2MM we have 3MM remaining. If the next month, 2020-02-01, consumes 1.5MM we have 1.5MM remaining. If the next month, 2020-03-01, consumes 2MM we have -0.5MM remaining and we finished consuming our amount during the month of 2020-03-01. This result of 2020-03-01 is what I am looking to obtain.

How can I obtain this value?

I want to get one result per row of the DataFrame and I need to perform aggregations over the rest of the DataFrame to look at historical rows. Therefore, I assume I need to use Window to calculate this value. However, I cannot figure out how to get the actual Window setup correctly.

My function within the Window is taking the starting amount called "opening_amount" and subtracting the burndown amount called "consume_amount" over the Window. For example,

```
  def followingWindowSpec: WindowSpec = Window.partitionBy(
    partitionCols : _*
  )
    .orderBy(orderByCols: _*)
    .rangeBetween(0, Window.unboundedFollowing)

  val burndownCompleteDateExpr = min(
    when(
      col("opening_amount")
        - sum(col("consume_amount"))
        .over(followingWindowSpec)
        <= lit(0),
      col("fiscal_dt")
    )
  )
    .over(followingWindowSpec)
```

I believe I need to use a Window that starts at the current row and looks forward. I've tried with Window(0, x) where x is some value.

When I set both Windows to be UnboundedFollowing I get each month's fiscal_dt.

When I set the consume_amount sum window to use UnboundedPreceding I get the correct results for the correct result for the first month, since it has NULL preceding values, but the following months either return the same month(for the first few months) or their own month(after the first few months).

If you could give me pointers about how to do the Windowing correctly, or what the correct approach is if I'm barking up the wrong tree, I would greatly appreciate it.

Sample data:

```
+----+----------+-------+--------+-------------+
|item|      date|opening|consumed|out_of_supply|
+----+----------+-------+--------+-------------+
| 101|2020-01-01|   3200|    2000|   2020-02-01|
| 101|2020-02-01|   4600|    1500|         null|
| 101|2020-03-01|   1500|    1300|   2020-04-01|
| 101|2020-04-01|   4000|     500|         null|
| 220|2020-01-01|   3400|    2000|   2020-02-01|
| 220|2020-02-01|   1600|    3000|   2020-02-01|
| 220|2020-03-01|    310|    1000|   2020-03-01|
| 220|2020-04-01|    680|     500|         null|
+----+----------+-------+--------+-------------+
```

For each row, I am summing up the consumed values from the row to n rows forward, increasing n one at a time, to see when the opening value is fully consumed.

For example, for item 101 in 2020-01-01, it opens with 3200, and consumes 2000 in the first month, ending the month with 1200. This 1200 is fully consumed by the 1500 in 2020-02-01, so 2020-02-01 is the month I am looking for.

For item 101 in 2020-02-01 it never gets fully consumed so I will return null as a default.

Comment: If "opening amount" and "consumed amount" are readily available in each row, why not simply do a `groupBy()` to aggregate `min(when($"opening_amt" <= $"consumed_amt", $"fiscal_dt"))`?

Comment: The issues is that the opening_amt is readily available in each row but the consumed_amt needs to be cumulative, so it needs to look at the other rows.

Comment: Given the following 3 rows, `("2020-01-01", 5000, 2000), ("2020-02-01", 3000, 1500), ("2020-03-01", 1500, 2000)`, doesn't the 3rd row have sufficient info by itself to result in `true` in the `when()` condition?

Comment: The third row would, yep. The first 2 would not though.

Comment: The first two rows will result in `null` hence be excluded.  So, something like `df.groupBy("item").agg(min(when($"opening_amt" <= $"consumed_amt", $"fiscal_dt")).as("outofstock_date")` should give what you need.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding your point here but I think there would still need to be an accumulation. It's likely that no individual row will ever meet the condition of opening_amt <= consumed_amt. In that case there would be no date given.

Comment: I think I misinterpreted from your example that your "opening amount" value is already updated for every month in the dataset.  Please see my answer to see if it addresses your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using `Window/rowsBetween()` to assemble for each row a list of `consumed` data in the following rows, which is then processed by a UDF to capture the out-of-supply `date`:

```
val df = Seq(
  (101, "2020-01-01", 3200, 2000),
  (101, "2020-02-01", 4600, 1500),
  (101, "2020-03-01", 1500, 1300),
  (101, "2020-04-01", 4000,  500),
  (220, "2020-01-01", 3400, 2000),
  (220, "2020-02-01", 1600, 3000),
  (220, "2020-03-01",  310, 1000),
  (220, "2020-04-01",  680,  500)
).toDF("item", "date", "opening", "consumed")

import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
val win1 = Window.partitionBy("item").orderBy("date").
  rowsBetween(0, Window.unboundedFollowing)

val outOfStockDate = udf { (opening: Int, list: Seq[Row]) =>
  @scala.annotation.tailrec
  def loop(ls: List[(String, Int)], dt: String, acc: Int): String = ls match {
    case Nil =>
      null
    case head :: tail =>
      val accNew = acc + head._2
      if (opening <= accNew) head._1 else loop(tail, head._1, accNew)
  }
  loop(list.map{ case Row(d: String, c: Int) => (d, c) }.toList, null, 0)
}

df.
  withColumn("consumed_list", collect_list(struct($"date", $"consumed")).over(win1)).
  withColumn("out_of_supply", outOfStockDate($"opening", $"consumed_list")).
  drop("consumed_list").
  show
// +----+----------+-------+--------+-------------+
// |item|      date|opening|consumed|out_of_supply|
// +----+----------+-------+--------+-------------+
// | 101|2020-01-01|   3200|    2000|   2020-02-01|
// | 101|2020-02-01|   4600|    1500|         null|
// | 101|2020-03-01|   1500|    1300|   2020-04-01|
// | 101|2020-04-01|   4000|     500|         null|
// | 220|2020-01-01|   3400|    2000|   2020-02-01|
// | 220|2020-02-01|   1600|    3000|   2020-02-01|
// | 220|2020-03-01|    310|    1000|   2020-03-01|
// | 220|2020-04-01|    680|     500|         null|
// +----+----------+-------+--------+-------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. One confounding factor in the actual use case is that each row has its own opening value and needs to get its own date. I.e. item 101 may have an opening inventory of 5000 in January but an opening inventory of 3000 in February. This also means the result cannot be by item but must be by item and date - and this makes it seem much more complex.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by "each row has its own opening value and needs to get its own date".  Perhaps you could elaborate by editing your question to add the wanted output based on some sample dataset.

Comment: Sorry about the delay. I got it working with another, much less elegant method, and had other work priorities. I've added sample data to show you the results I had in mind. I've been working on it myself in my free time and have yet to resolve it.

Comment: So, based on your latest sample data, the "opening" quantity in each row is subject to external changes not deducible from prior "opening"/"consumed" data.  Please see my revised solution.

Comment: Yes, the opening amount comes to us from another system and changes from month to month. I.e. if opening was 3000 in one month, and we received deliveries of 2000 and consume of 1000 the opening the next month is 4000. We don't know what the actual deliveries and consume was until they provide us that data.

Comment: In your results the month of 2020-03-01 for item 101 should be out of supply in 2020-04-01. The rest of the results do seem correct. Your code makes sense to me so I'm not sure why that result is off. Also, your code is hugely informational so thank you a ton for it. I've struggled with setting up UDFs before. We're close!

Comment: My bad.  Some logical glitches in the UDF.  Method revised.

Comment: I've had the chance to try it out and it works perfectly! Thank you very much!